# MATLAB "filter" function in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, matlab, filter

I've been tasked with recoding a MATLAB script into C or C++, and I'm having a little difficulty wrapping my head around this filter function (filter(a, b, x)). Does anyone know of a simple way to do this, or an existing C library that accomplishes the same thing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just implement the filter function as described [here](http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/data_analysis/bqm3i7m-1.html). This resembles just a tapped delay-line filter, where `b` and `a` are coefficients and `x` is the input data:

```
a[1]y[n] = b[1]x[n]+b[2]x[n-1]+...+b[N]x[n-B+1]-a[2]y[n-1]-...-a[N]y[n-N+1]
```

You only have to take care about not-yet-existing indices, which are denoted by the square brackets. `a` and `b` are vectors of length `N`.

Comment: Seems that your link is obsolete now. May be this one was meant: 
http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/filter.html